# CSS minimum opacity value allowed

Tags: css, opacity

In CSS when I change the `opacity` value of a button it is still clickable to an extent. I lowered my opacity setting down to `0.005` (so that the button is practically hidden, but it still works and can be interacted with), when I set the value to `0.000000000000000000000000000000000001` though, for example, it just becomes completely hidden and can no longer be clicked.

(Surely this tiny float is just rounded to `0`, and this causes the problem, but I'm wondering, just because `0.005` works in my browser, doesn't mean it works in all browsers, and I NEED this button click-able in all browsers).

Does anyone know the minimum value it can tolerate across ALL browsers?

Comment: Seems like an odd problem to have to solve.

Comment: Are you...trying to put a clickable area on top of an image, or something? Because there are alternatives.

Comment: `opacity: 0` is the minimum value, and the elements should still be clickable.

Comment: I agree with @zzzzBov ... opacity 0 should still be clickable. (I don't know if super huge floats affect this though...) Could you give us an example?

Comment: 0 opacity - http://jsfiddle.net/y7mq23ra/
.0...1 opacity - http://jsfiddle.net/gbd45gbq/
and it should be noted that I totally ripped of the button code for example purposes from another fiddle and think the author is amazing whoever they are.  Only changing `display` should affect clickability, not `opacity`

Comment: @DavidThomas  A clickable iFrame (YouTube Video) ontop of an image of "play video".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as @zzzzbov mentioned: `0` is the minimum.

**Note:** Since `0` means "no opacity", it basically starts from `0.01`

**The least is**

```
opacity: 0.01;
```

**The most is:**

```
 opacity: 0.99;
```

Comment: "Minimum" is defined as "the least amount possible", and you say the minimum is `0` and the least is `0.01`. But clearly `0 != 0.01`. Can you clarify? And where do `0.01` and `0.99` come from? The [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#propdef-opacity) clearly says the value of `opacity` has an [`<alpha-value>`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#typedef-alpha-value) value, which can be a number from `0` to `1`.

Comment: @Oriol Why use opacity in the first place if the value is going to be 0. If the value is between 0.01 and 0.99, you have some measure of opacity but when the value is 1, you have none. One can use 1 as the value when reversing a previous value that is less than 1.

Comment: @Oriol some platforms completely ignore an object if opacity is 0, and it becomes "hidden" and un-interactable... so above is posted the minimum value of opacity where object interactivity (as well as potentially other values) is(are) retained.

Answer (score 0):

its depends on your convenience that how much opacity you want to set. 
   For creating trasperant object:

```
object {
 opacity: 0.6;
}
```

For "HOVER' effect of object:

```
object:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

I think opacity 0.6 will be the ok.